# Using MomentJS to add a month returns a different day

Tags: momentjs

Using MomentJS and adding a month, I wouldn't expect the day to change:

```
let date = moment('1995-01-25'); 
date.add(2, 'month');
console.log(date.day()); // Expected 25, outputs 6
```

Comment: are you sure that `yyyy-MM-dd` us the expected format by `moment`?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) yyyy-MM-dd is acceptable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`date()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/) to get date of the month, [`day()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) returns the day of the week (Sunday as 0, ...,  Saturday as 6.).

See code sample:

```js
let date = moment('1995-01-25'); 
date.add(2, 'month');
console.log(date.format());
console.log(date.day());   // Day of the week
console.log(date.date());  // Day of the month
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```